# Null Pointer Exception in Creating a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to implement a `Sliding Menu`. When the user clicks on a button, then I want to display two fragments, one for clicking a photo and the other to choose Date and Time. I am using DatePickerFragment to pick the date. I am getting a `NullPointerException`

```
MainActivity()

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // on first time display view for first nav item
        displayView(0);
    }
}
private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        //HomeFragment homeFragment = null;
        //ImageFragment imageFragment=null;
        Fragment fragment=null;
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        DateTimeFragment datetime=null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment= new HomeFragment();
            break;

        case 1: 
            fragment=new ImageFragment();
            datetime=new DateTimeFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if(fragment!=null)
        {
            ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
            if(datetime!=null)
            {
                ft.replace(R.id.datetime_container, datetime);
            }
            ft.commit();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

DateTimeFragment

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class DateTimeFragment extends Fragment {

     private EditText editStartDate;
     private EditText editEndDate;
     @Override 
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       { 
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
         final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
            int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            ImageButton startDate=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.start_date_button);
            editStartDate = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.startDate);
            editStartDate.setText(Integer.toString(dd)+ "/" + Integer.toString(mm) +"/"+ Integer.toString(yy));

            ImageButton endDate=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.end_date_button);
            editEndDate = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.endDate);
            editEndDate.setText(Integer.toString(dd)+ "/" + Integer.toString(mm) +"/"+ Integer.toString(yy));

             AutoCompleteTextView location= (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.location);
             location.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.list_layout));

             startDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           try
                            {
                               DialogFragment newFragment= (DialogFragment) new DatePickerFragment(R.id.startDate);
                               newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
                            }

                            catch(Exception e)
                            {

                                return ;
                            }
                    }
                });

             endDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            try
                            {
                                 DialogFragment newFragment= (DialogFragment) new DatePickerFragment(R.id.endDate);
                                 newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

                            }
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                return ;
                            }
            }
        });

         return v;
      }

     public void onComplete(String date, int id) {
            if(id==R.id.start_date_button)
             editStartDate.setText(date);
            else if(id==R.id.end_date_button)
             editEndDate.setText(date); 

        }
}
```

The `imageFragment` by itself displays properly, but when I try to display the `DateFragment`, I get an error as shown:

```
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): Process: com.example.makemyday, PID: 1799
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.example.makemyday.DateTimeFragment.onCreateView(DateTimeFragment.java:31)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
12-26 16:17:39.023: E/AndroidRuntime(1799):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check line num 31 of your DateTimeFragment.java class.

Comment: also post the layout files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, you get Null Pointer Exception thrown by code in your DateTimeFragment class in line 31. Can be some of your layout element like ImageButtons are not part of the layout (or use different Id) so your `findViewById()` return `null`

Comment: Could you suggest how I can implement OnComplete method for DatePicker fragment?